# Expression Engine: member update hook

Tags: hook, expressionengine

Is there a hook for when a member's details are updated either by the user or by the admin system?

What i'm trying to do is have two custom fields; long and lat which are populated by using google maps api's geocoding functions.

I need this to be automatic so that when an account is created, a call is made and the long/lat fields are updated and if the user is updated then we check to see if the address data has changed and if it has, re-request the long/lat.

I can find hooks for member create but not for update unless i've not spotted something.

Is there one stashed away somewhere?  Or is it possible I can crow-bar one in somehow?

The version of expression engine is 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hook for the `update_member()` method, you are correct. You could look at using the `session_start` hook, and then checking for `$_POST['edit_profile']` within that hook method ... all of the new data should be in `$_POST`, with `$_POST['id']` being the `member_id`.